# Why is a process being shown while using "jobs" command after killing the process manually?

Tags: bash, kill, ps, process-management, jobs

Why is the parole(just a media palyer) still listed in the "JOBS" command output even after killing maually and why is not listed in the "PS" command output ?

1. Does this mean the process is still runnig in background(ps:when i issued kill command the media playe[parole] is closed))?
2. If running why is it not listed in the "PS" command output ? If not running what is the meaning of the output for "JOBS" command.

[image: List of commands entered]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jobs will apear one last time after **any** command once terminated.

see below

```
 > sleep 30 &
[1] 134042
 > ps
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
 134009 pts/4    00:00:00 bash
 134042 pts/4    00:00:00 sleep
 134043 pts/4    00:00:00 ps
 > kill 134042
 > date
Mon Aug  3 22:11:58 CEST 2020
[1]+  Terminated              sleep 30
 > jobs
 >
```

according to `man bash`, JOB CONTROL

> The  shell  learns immediately whenever a job changes state.
> Normally, bash waits until it is about to print a prompt before
> reporting changes in a job's status so as to not interrupt any other output.

so you can even use an empty command (i.e. press <kbd>return</kbd>), to see the `done` line.

Comment: Thank you that cleared many of my doubts :)

Comment: Also, a job that is stopped cannot receive a signal (the default is sigterm, and it may have a handler installed). So after you kill it, it needs to run just to terminate and have the shell notice, to get its status from the process list. A process is like Schrodinger's cat -- it is not truly dead until it is observed to be dead.